# date.timezone switch not found in php.ini file

Tags: php

i have a problem with php.ini file.
i need to change current date and time in wamp server in local.
i know that for this should change **date.timezone** switch in **php.ini** file.
i want change it like this that is my  time zone location

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Tehran"
```

but i do not find this switch in php.ini for change when open in notepad.
i am using **wamp 1.7.3**.
please help me for find and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be in the php.ini file looking like this :

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = UTC
```

Alternatively, try updating WAMP to the latest version. The above settings are from my php.ini from WAMP version 2.

Comment: Yes I forced install new version of Wamp

Answer (score 2):

WAMP 1.7.3 comes with PHP 5.2. which is supposed to have the date.timezone config.

Maybe you can manually add it.

Something like

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; ; Module Settings ; ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[Date] 
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions ; 
http://php.net/date.timezone 
date.timezone = Europe/London
```